# SalesForce outbound message schema wsdl

Tags: salesforce

We are building a POC project for a client, we are supposed to build a listner for receiving notificagtion from SalesForce, we have a few samples, by comparing the schema googled from SalesForce (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_wsdl.htm) I have a rough idea.

However I cannot find the complete WSDL definition, could anyone please help me pointing me a location to download this WSDL instead I try to build it from the scratch myself? Much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have administrative access to a Salesforce organisation you can export the WSDL from the API WSDL page. It is accessible from User Name > Setup > Develop > API.

There are different API WSDL files for different purposes so select the one that works for you. If you need to be specific to your client's customisations then you will need to export the WSDL from their organisation.

[image: The Salesforce API WSDL page]

If you just need a standard Salesforce WSDL you can sign up for a free [developer](http://developer.force.com/) account on salesforce to get access to this page.

Comment: that's true in general, but not for outbound messaging.

Comment: thanks, this helps, but I didnt find the notifications() call in the enterprise WSDL port types, could you please help. thanks

Comment: its not in the enterprise WSDL, see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

The WSDL depends on the outbound message configuration, you need to create your workflow outbound messaging config, at that point you can then download the WSDL for that outbound message setup via the Endpoint WSDL field.

[image: outbound messaging details]

Comment: @Tommy-Wang I think you should mark this as the answer to your question instead of mine as this one is correct (whereas mine is not).